# JS event bubbling prevents checkbox checked status

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, dom-events

I try to understand the difference between event bubbling and event tunnelling (capture in Javascript).

In wpf you have to handle the event before the event reach the control. In js this seems not to be the case.

Why is there no difference between capture true and false? I expected, that the checkbox is checked in the example at the bottom. I do not want to prevent event propagation but just understand this effect.

```js
document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML += "Sorry! <code>preventDefault()</code> won't let you check this!<br>";
  event.preventDefault();
}, {
  capture: false
});
```

```html
<p>Please click on the checkbox control.</p>

<form>
  <label for="id-checkbox">Checkbox:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="id-checkbox" />
</form>

<div id="output-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained is the documentation, this var is a boolen indicating if the event should be passed to the current event handler before passing to the next element's event listener.
Just understand that when you trigger an event in js it's first passed to the "first" element and go deeper and deeper. Then, when it reach the deepest element, the event will go back to the first one (we speak about bubbling).

This example should help you to understand :

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert("event from the checkbox");
});

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert("event from the body");
}, {
  capture: false
});
```

```html
<p>Please click on the checkbox control.</p>

<form>
  <label for="id-checkbox">Checkbox:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="id-checkbox" />
</form>

<div id="output-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) `useCapture` option only affects the order in which the event is propagated down the DOM tree.

> A Boolean indicating whether events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.

As soon as your snippet has only one event listener you indeed can not notice any observable effect.
However, if you add another one i.e.

```
document.querySelector("#id-checkbox").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML += "Checkbox capture";       
});
```

you will notice how the order of execution changes depending on the outer handler capture option.
If you want checkbox to be checked you may use it like this.

```
document.querySelector("#id-checkbox").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();    
    document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML += "Checkbox capture";       
});
```

Here `stopPropagation` prevents event bubbling. So event won't be handled up in the DOM tree and `preventDefault` won't be called.
If you want just the upper handler to execute you can use

```
document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("output-box").innerHTML += "Sorry! <code>preventDefault()</code> won't let you check this!<br>";
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}, {
  capture: true
});
```

Here the combination of `capture: true` and `stopPropagation` prevents capturing event down the DOM tree.

Comment: But then it doesn't work as explained with this image: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/images/eventflow.svg

I would argue, that you need the capturing phase to prevent the event handling of the control but this seems not to be the case.

Comment: What this picture tells is that capture phase is performed in order to determine the event target. If you examine `event.target` of your handler it will show HTMLInput element although you handle "html" tag click not your checkbox. The second bubbling phase is aimed to execute ALL the subscribers. So if you'll have 2 subscribers like in my example both will be executed. However, if you want to avoid this you can add `event.stopPropagation();` in your checkbox handler. This will make your checkbox selected

Comment: If I have stopPropagation with Capture true/false then I can always check the checkbox. But the event is discarded isn't?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "discarded". My point is that stopPropagation prevents further bubbling. That's why if you handle it somewhere on checkbox level it won't reach html-level handlers which fires preventDefault.

Comment: if I stopPropagation with capture = true it is still possible to check the checkbox.

Comment: If you don't want it to be checked when setting capture = true you need also add stopPropagation for your html-level handler in order to prevent further handling of event down the DOM tree. https://jsfiddle.net/z7pah642/2/